# Dapper cannot pass the data to the database

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dapper

I am having a problem where I cannot insert nor update to the database. I am using Dapper and using nested class for the model that I want to pass the data on.

I am having an error which is:

```
The member Information of type TestProject.Models.Information cannot be used as a parameter value
```

My model is below:

```
public class Member
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Information MemberInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Information
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller is below:

```
public IHttpActionResult SetMemberInfo(Member models)
{
    using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection()))
    {
        conn.Open();

        int rowsAffected = conn.Execute("MemberInformation", models, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        trans.Complete();

        return rowsAffected;
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

My stored procedure is below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[MemberInformation]
(
    @Username   NVARCHAR(100),
    @Password   NVARCHAR(100),
    @Email      NVARCHAR(100),
    @City       NVARCHAR(100),
    @State      NVARCHAR(100),
    @BirthDate  DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
 // TODO: Do something with the data
END
```

And I pass the data to the controller from client side is below:

```
var models = {
    "Username": "MyUsername",
    "Password": "MyPassword",
    "MemberInfo": {
        "Email": "MyEmail",
        "City": "MyCity",
        "State": "MyState",
        "BirthDate": "2017-08-23"
    }
};

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "http://localhost/SetMemberInfo",
                data: JSON.stringify(models),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            });
```

But if I didn't make it into nested class (means all data in the Information class moved to the Member class), everything works fine.

How can I tell dapper to separate the data from nested class and break it into a single class instead, even though in the application level is nested class.

Or is there any other solutions for this?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't think Dapper has this kind of support for nested objects as parameters.

What you can try is:

1. Create a DTO exactly as your stored procedure expects and map your Member object to this new type.

```
public class MemberInformationParameter
{
    public MemberInformationParameter(Member member)
    {
            Username = member.Username;
            Password = member.Password;
            Email = member.MemberInfo.Email;
            City = member.MemberInfo.City;
            State = member.MemberInfo.State;
            BirthDate = member.MemberInfo.BirthDate;
    }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

2. Or just pass the arguments as a dynamic object with the syntax:

   conn.Execute("MemberInformation", new { Property1: value1, Property2: value2 }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

Comment: Hi, so do you think is because the Dapper didn't have this kind of support, I should make 3 classses? 2 of them is like my question above (with nested class, and this is only usable when trying to pass the data from client to the server side), and then when want to go to the DB, I should make 1 more class (like your answer no 1) that is not nested class at all (this class purpose is solely for connection between DB and Dapper), so that the DB can understand it? For the no 2, I am not quite understand it, what does it means by property1 and value1? is that from nested class? Thanks

Comment: Well, is all up to you! In my opinion dynamic object fits best, because you will only use this logic at the Data layer level and you are already receiving your structured object that contains all the necessary information. So everytime your Member class changes, it will generate an error in the data access method, making it consistent.

Comment: Hi, one more that I didn't get when using the dynamic object.. is the property and value will be like the following: `conn.Execute("MemberInformation", new { Email: models.MemberInfo.Email, City: models.MemberInfo.City (and so on) }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);` ? Thanks

Comment: Exactly, passing all the information as a single flat object, without nesting properties.

Comment: You are welcome! It will be good for the other developers if you accept my response as the answer, so they can use as their solutions too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
[Table("studentclass")]
public partial class Studentclass
{
    public Studentclass()
    {
        Studentclasssyllabus = new HashSet<Studentclasssyllabus>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Studentid { get; set; }
    public int Subjectclassid { get; set; }

    [Write(false)]
    [Computed]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    [Write(false)]
    [Computed]
    public virtual Subjectclass Subjectclass { get; set; }

    [Write(false)]
    [Computed]
    public virtual ICollection<Studentclasssyllabus> Studentclasssyllabus { get; set; 
}
```

and

```
[Table("schedule")]
public partial class Schedule
{
    public Schedule()
    {
        Attendance = new HashSet<Attendance>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Lecturerid { get; set; }
    public int? Subjectclassid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Starttime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Endtime { get; set; }
    public int? Roomstatus { get; set; }
    public string Ownerjitsiid { get; set; }
    public string Generateroomname { get; set; }

    [Write(false)]
    [Computed]
    public virtual Lecturer Lecturer { get; set; }

    [Write(false)]
    [Computed]
    public virtual Subjectclass Subjectclass { get; set; }

    [Write(false)]
    [Computed]
    public virtual ICollection<Attendance> Attendance { get; set; }
}
```

}

when I set this tag "[Write(false)][Computed]" to model. when dapper update entities it will be passed that parameter

Answer (score 1):

1. add the package for dapperextentions
2. Dapper extentions has a function called insert or update that could accept a model like Member object.
3. AutoMap(); will map all other properties as long as you have the same name for the field.

```
public class MemberMapper : DapperExtensions.Mapper.ClassMapper<Member>
    {
        public MemberMapper()
        {
           Table("TableName if diffrent than the Model calss name");
           Map(f => f.MemberInfo).Ignore();
           AutoMap();
        }
    }
```